# Failed to Fetch error while updating Oracle Cloud

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, oracle, xrdp

I am using Oracle Cloud canonical ubuntu 22.04 and canonical ubuntu 22.04 minimal. Both having same error.

When i am run `sudo apt update` i get below error

**Error :**

```
E: Failed to fetch http://us-sanjose-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us-sanjose-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us-sanjose-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
deb http://us-sanjose-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy multiv>
# deb-src http://us-sanjose-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy >
deb http://us-sanjose-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-update>
# deb-src http://us-sanjose-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy->

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us-sanjose-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-backpo>
# deb-src http://us-sanjose-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy->

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Where did you get your source URLS & most importantly what *architecture* are you using??   I notice *ports* URLs which means a *riscv64*, *arm64*, *armhf*, *ppc64el* etc or a PORT, and yet I also see a *i386* line in your provided post, and *i386* is **NOT** a port but a primary architecture found in *archive*.  Your sources have been I bet modified to mix architectures; undo that change  (*You didn't provide architecture details; but that's what I see*)

Comment: These URL are default after installing. I am using Oracle Cloud ARM Instance.

Comment: The image used at install and your sources will vary depending on the architecture you're using. If it's a cloud instance; you'll decide that on selection/purchase of the instance.. PORTS apply to *arm64*, *armhf*, *riscv64*, *ppc64el* and the PORT architectures... however the main archives will be used if your architecture is *amd64* (where *i386* or the 32-bit architecture version of *amd64* is found).  If you're using *arm64* for example; the 32bit version is *armhf* and **not** *i386*.